# Routing Streaming Video from Server to Multiple Client Video element

Tags: c#, php, network-programming, video-streaming

I am building this application which uses CCTV camera for streaming feeds to an end user on browser. We want to route this stream to our server and then would like to forward it to user. We are searching for some solution in open source as well as paid solution. We have only came across VLMa server which we don't think would be sufficient. Can any one please suggest a programmatic way of routing this or a ready made solution which helps us in achieving this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried following solutions for this problem.

1. http://www.wowza.com/ 
   This is a paid version. But, It performs very well for its price. you get lots of functionality for what you are paying.
2. http://code.google.com/p/red5/
   This one is Open Source version. It is based on Java Servlet. So, If your Solutions require only .Net then this may not be for you. Ours was in php so, We managed to have a working solution with this approach. It also works really well provided more management skills are required.
3. VLMa Server
   This was our initial try. It did not matched our requirement to 100%. But, If few functionality is added then it could really compete with above 2.

Hope it helps you.
Thanks.